# With Krita, How to Create 'Pressure Sensitive' Circles and Curves With Brush Tool?

Tags: drawing-tablet, krita, bezier-curve, brush-dynamics

I'm using Krita 4.2.7.1 on Windows 10 x64.

With the brush tool selected and using the keyboard shortcut 'v', I'm able to create straight lines whose fill takes into account both the pressure applied by my Wacom tablet pen as well as the selected brush type. I would like to replicate this behaviour with circles and curves.

AFAIK there no equivalent shortcuts, so I manually select these tools, i.e. ellipse tool and bezier curve tool and draw. The created lines don't take into account the pressure I applied with my pen (darkest line possible), however the brush is used.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

My current work-around is to create the lines as above and using alpha-locking go over them with the brush to achieve the pressure sensitivity.

Comment: I guess it's impossible for software to know how do you want the pressure to be distributed along a bezier or ellipse curve. That's because you never draw them, you actually give only a drawing command by clicking the places of some key points and handles. You must do a 2nd pass as you described or use some other "adapt to pressure beforehand or afterwards" - method

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your comment! What I had in my head was evenly distributing the pressure across the curve or ellipse based on how hard you press down when initiating/releasing. So, I suppose that is the same thing as your 'adapt to pressure beforehand or afterwards' method.

Comment: To get that functionality someone must program it. An interested and competent programmer is needed. Me and many others who splash colors and lines are out of the question, I guess. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There are assistant tools to help you confine your brush stroke to a shape like physical rulers. The Assistant tool is denoted by a triangular set square like this [image: assistant tool icon]. Activate the assistant tool and go to the Tool Options docker. There select either Ellipse or Concentric Ellipse.
[image: tool option docker for assistant tool]

Draw your assistant on the canvas. Choose the brush that you want to use to make the circle. Now go to the Tool Options docker and check "Snap to Assistants" option. This will snap your brush stroke to the assistant that you have drawn.

Now you can draw a circle which can have strokes affected by the pressure sensitivity.

There are other assistants too. You can read more about them in the official manual [here](https://docs.krita.org/en/user_manual/painting_with_assistants.html#types).

Comment: This is a really nice drawing feauture in Kirta. There's also a nice youtube video tutorial by Orphanlast showing [how to use Krita Assistants](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6VRaVkrEII&t=256s&ab_channel=Orphanlast)